# Node 20 error: `EACCES: permission denied` on `fs.writeFileSync` to file in TMPDIR

Tags: node.js, node.js-fs

The bug.mjs: open `/tmp/test/foo.json`, read and append k-v to save.

Update: **It works with Node 18, but failed with Node 20/21**:

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import os from 'os'

function modify(fsPath, key, value) {
  let dir = path.dirname(fsPath)
  if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) fs.mkdirSync(dir, { recursive: true })
  let content = fs.readFileSync(fsPath, { encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'a+' })
  content = content || '{}'
  content = JSON.parse(content)
  content[key] = value
  content = JSON.stringify(content)
  fs.writeFileSync(fsPath, content, { encoding: 'utf8' })
}

const p = path.join(os.tmpdir(),  'foo.json')
modify(p, 'key', 'foobar')
```

`node bug.mjs`:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/folders/7q/r_8_1r5d5bb0dfycljk5pr1h0000gn/T/test/foo.json'
    at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2342:20)
    at modify (file:///Users/fannheyward/bug.mjs:13:6)
    at file:///Users/fannheyward/bug.mjs:17:1
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:222:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:323:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:120:12) {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/var/folders/7q/r_8_1r5d5bb0dfycljk5pr1h0000gn/T/test/foo.json'
}
```

The `/var/folders/7q/r_8_1r5d5bb0dfycljk5pr1h0000gn/T/test/foo.json` is created but with no permission:

```
----------  1 fannheyward  staff     0B  3 14 09:31 /var/folders/7q/r_8_1r5d5bb0dfycljk5pr1h0000gn/T/test/foo.json
```

Update 2: the folder is accessible

```
drwxr-xr-x@  3 fannheyward  staff    96B  3 14 09:42 test/
```

Update 3: both Node 18 and 20 are installed with `brew`:

```
❯ /opt/homebrew/opt/node@18/bin/node --version
v18.19.1

❯ /opt/homebrew/opt/node@20/bin/node --version
v20.11.1
```

Comment: The program or user probably doesn't have write permissions. Check that first, then check if you can access that folder.

Comment: @code the folder is accessible

Comment: @Slbox It's on macOS

Comment: When you claim it works in one version and not another, remember to explain how you're testing that, because different installs on the same machine can have wildly different permissions depending on where they live and who installed them, how =) (For instance: MacOS has in recent versions _drastically_ locked down filesystem access: are both Node versions listed in the "full disk access" list?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans both are installed with `brew`

Comment: Just quickly checking issues, what happens if you apply the same trick that https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11422 uses, using `fs.realpathSync(os.tmpdir())` instead of just `os.tmpdir()`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans unlucky with `fs.realpathSync(os.tmpdir())`, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `fs.readFileSync(fsPath, { flag: 'a+' }).toString('utf8')`

Some links:

- https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/48658
- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/49888
- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/52079
- https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/pull/1202